# Graph Api Webhook Instagram Comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, instagram, facebook-webhooks

I try to integrate Instagram into my web app. I need receive webhook by each comment/reply in my media. But I couldn't identify webhook comment  parent ID because webhook response doesn't contain such information. Is there any way I can Find this.
Im using graph api version 6.0

Instagram Webhook Dummy Response for comment

```
[
{   'id': '123xxxxx',  # account Id
     'time': 1588854464, 
      'changes': 
      [
          {'value': 
            {
            'id': '345xxx',  # comment/ reply Id
             'text': 'hello world'
            }, 
          'field': 'comments'
          }
       ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Use the comment id to request the comment’s details, and check the `media` field?

Comment: @CBroe yes I use media field I get the post/media id. But how can I get the parent ID of this comment ?

Comment: Not sure if that’s possible, the available fields are listed under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/comment/#returnable-fields I don’t know what `replies` contains, but that sounds like it was the other direction, connection a comment with its “children”.

Comment: @CBroe I read the doc. but I couldn't find anyway to get the parent Id of this comment if it has.

Comment: @MUsmanWahab we faced same issue, now we treat all comments regardless their level (top or reply) as a top-level comments.

Comment: I had the same problem, so I reported it to Facebook...
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/371608330567205/ 
Their answer is basically... "nope"